# How do I append to an alist in scheme?

Tags: list, lisp, scheme, associative

Adding an element to the head of an alist (Associative list) is simple enough:

```
> (cons '(ding . 53) '((foo . 42) (bar . 27)))
((ding . 53) (foo . 42) (bar . 27))
```

Appending to the tail of an alist is a bit trickier though. After some experimenting, I produced this:

```
> (define (alist-append alist pair) `(,@alist ,pair))
> (alist-append '((foo . 42) (bar . 27)) '(ding . 53))
'((foo . 42) (bar . 27) (ding . 53))
```

However, it seems to me, that this isn't the idiomatic solution. So how is this usually done in scheme? Or is this in fact the way?

Comment: I am in awe of people who can understand languages like Scheme

Comment: So am I ;) Seriously though, it's not that foreign as it appears; It just has a funny syntax. After a while, you stop noticing the funnyness. I'm just hobby-hacking with scheme, yet I almost have become used to it already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't append to an a-list.  You cons onto an a-list.

An a-list is logically a set of associations.  You don't care about the order of elements in a set.  All you care about is presence or absence of a particular element.  In the case of an a-list, all you care about is whether there exists an association for a given tag (i.e., a pair whose CAR is the specified value), and, given that association, the associated value (i.e., in this implementation, the CDR of the pair).

Comment: I agree with the consing part in this answer and the others, but I do think that it *can* make sense to care about the order. It is also called an a*list* and not an a*set*. For example, when you cons bindings (name . value) onto an alist that represents an environment, you want more recent bindings to shadow older bindings with the same name instead of overwriting them (see also Matthias' answer).

Answer (score 8):

Common Lisp defines a function called [ACONS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_acons.htm) for exactly this purpose, where

```
(acons key value alist)
```

is equivalent to:

```
(cons (cons key value) alist)
```

This strongly suggests that simply consing onto an alist is idiomatic.  Note that this means two things:

1. As searches are usually performed from front to back, recently added associations take precedence over older ones.  This can be used for a naive implementation of both lexical and dynamic environments.
2. While consing onto a list is O(1), appending is generally O(n) where n is the length of the list, so the idiomatic usage is best for performance as well as being stylistically preferable.